# non-orthogonal contrasts in R

Tags: contrasts

I am running ANOVA and doing non-orthogonal contrasts. Non-orthogonal contrasts are not supposed to completely partition the sum of squares of treatments. But what I got from R is not what is supposed to be.

Here is my R code

```
painlevel=c(3,4,4,5,2,3,4,3,6,7,8,5,4,6,5,8,6,7,7,6,5,6,7,8)
drug=c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8),rep("C",8))
mydata=data.frame(painlevel,drug)  # This is my data
mat <-matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0),nrow=3, byrow=F)
mymat <- solve(t(mat))
contrasts(mydata$drug) <- mymat[,2:3]
afit <-lm(painlevel~drug,mydata)
summary.aov(afit,split=list(drug=list("c1"=1,"c2"=2)))
```

Here is the R output

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
drug         2  42.75   21.38   16.70 4.56e-05 ***
  drug: c1   1  15.19   15.19   11.87 0.002428 ** 
  drug: c2   1  27.56   27.56   21.54 0.000141 ***
Residuals   21  26.87    1.28                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Notice that the sum of squares for the two contrasts add up to the treatment sum of squares. I did the calculations by hand, the sum of squares for the first contrast given by R is incorrect while the second is correct.

If the contrasts are orthogonal, then everything is fine. Does anybody know why R gave the incorrect sum of squares for non-orthogonal contrasts? And how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I found this link useful to understand your issue: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html